# Applying transitions to MapControl on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm writing a small app for a [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) project and I wanted to animate my map in application.

To display a map I'm using [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx), and there is hard to find useful examples for this element, because it's new in Windows Phone 8.1.

And now I would like to ask how to animate the map. I've tried to apply an transitions (from Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.*) to my MapControl element, but some of them cannot be added or doesn't work.

I will be very grateful for any advices. Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify what kind of transitions are you looking for? MapControl has built-in `TrySetViewAsync()` function with the argument `MapAnimationKind` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn637062.aspx . Does it suit your needs? It covers just the basics, but maybe it's enough for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. It totaly suit what I wanted to achieve. Before I was changing center by modifying MapControl.Center property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe their is any built in method for doing transitions/animations, however you might be able to port over some the functionality I created for the Bing Maps JavaScript control to WP. You can find a blog post here:

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/08/07/bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-javascript/

I also wrote a C# version for Bing Maps Win8 here:

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/25/part-2-bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-net/